# Learn the inner workings of web browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser, dom-events

I've just recently started looking into the details of which events fire when in what browsers when an html page is loaded, and at how to use JavaScript, especially jQuery, to leverage those events to make a page do exactly what I want, when I want.

It seems like knowledge of when and how browsers set off events and how to access them in JavaScript is a pretty big deal, but there isn't really one, good place to go and learn about it.  There are thousands upon thousands of juicy tidbits which contain all the information, many of which are even grouped on certain sites (like this one), but you generally have to know what you're looking for, which prevents a lot of the "stumble upon" effect when learning about a topic.

**So is there a good place to learn about all the intricacies of something like the order of events when a page is loaded, or what exactly browsers do during an AJAX call, or just about how browsers deal with an general JavaScript event?**

Comment: I guess the "inner workings" and "how browsers deal with a javascript event" are a bit too complex and far stretched to just find one resource for.

Comment: @pimvdb Yep, I realize it's a pretty broad topic.  Oddly enough, though, the answers so far pretty much cover just as broad a spectrum yet hit it on the spot; I especially like Oliver's link--it obviously doesn't have all the answers, but it does a lot to point the learner in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't had time to read it myself but looks quite promising:

[How Browsers Work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)

Comment: Yes, it's written by 100% pros.

Comment: @Boldewyn Maybe it's just me, but you sound (?) sarcastic.

Comment: No, no. Not at all. Paul Irish, the editor, proved his profound knowledge in lots of situations, for example, with his 'bulletproof @font-face' post. Actually, I +1'ed the answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

The holy grail of Javascript (events): [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try Sitepoint.com http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-from-scratch/ They do some very good and easy to read books and online guides for every skill level.